App Locker for other applications in my application
I'm developing an android application with kotlin which I need to lock some installed apps in my device.
first of all I'll display all installed app in a fragment and I did this successfully.
second user will choose an app of them and set password for this app and I did that too and save app name, package name and password in room database.
now I want to lock applications that user set password for with its password, I mean no one can open any of these application without entering the password.
how can I do that ?
I searched for a long time and I can't find any helpful answer.
